# App Engine 401/403 Status Codes Not Working on WebApp2

Tags: google-app-engine, http-status-codes, webapp2

I am trying to raise a 401/403 status for when a user attempts to access something they don't have privileges to.  I used the [Webapp2 Exceptions](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/exceptions.html) example which generates the proper error codes for 404/500 "natural" events.  Such as going to http://localhost:8080/nourl generates the proper 404 and messing up code generates a 500.  But when I use the method such as below to set the code using self.error(XXX) I see the code in the console but it does not show up in the browser.  EG If you leave self.error() empty it generates the proper 500 code.  If you use self.error(500) the console outputs:

```
INFO     2012-05-09 18:25:29,549 dev_appserver.py:2891] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

But the browser is completely blank.  Below is an example app that exhibits this behaviour.  Simply change the self.error() line to the desired code and run.  The expected result would be that it generates the proper response to the browser based on the code supplied, not just when a "natural" event occurs such as 404.

main.py

```
import webapp2
import wsgiref.handlers
import logging
from google.appengine.api import users


class HomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            self.response.out.write("Hi :1", user.nickname)
        else:
            self.error(401)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/', HomeHandler),
], debug=True)


def handle_401(request, response, exception):
    logging.exception(exception)
    response.write("401 Error")
    response.set_status(401)


def handle_403(request, response, exception):
    logging.exception(exception)
    response.write("403 Error")
    response.set_status(403)


def handle_404(request, response, exception):
    logging.exception(exception)
    response.write("404 Error")
    response.set_status(404)


def handle_500(request, response, exception):
    logging.exception(exception)
    response.write("500 Error")
    response.set_status(500)

app.error_handlers[401] = handle_401
app.error_handlers[403] = handle_403
app.error_handlers[404] = handle_404
app.error_handlers[500] = handle_500


#  Run the application
def main():
    app.run()
```

app.yaml

```
application: 401test
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>you are using py27 with threadsafe environment. 
in app.yaml you set `script: main.app` so the code after app is defined is not executed.</strike>

didn't test it but this should work:

```
# create a bare app 
bare_app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(debug=True)

#define the error handlers
def handle_401(request, response, exception):
    logging.exception(exception)
    response.write("401 Error")
    response.set_status(401)

def handle_403(request, response, exception):
    logging.exception(exception)
    response.write("403 Error")
    response.set_status(403)


def handle_404(request, response, exception):
    logging.exception(exception)
    response.write("404 Error")
    response.set_status(404)


def handle_500(request, response, exception):
    logging.exception(exception)
    response.write("500 Error")
    response.set_status(500)

# add the error handlers
bare_app.error_handlers[401] = handle_401
bare_app.error_handlers[403] = handle_403
bare_app.error_handlers[404] = handle_404
bare_app.error_handlers[500] = handle_500


bare_app.router.add((r'/', HomeHandler))

app = bare_app
```

**edit**:
use self.abort() instead of self.error()
http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/exceptions.html#abort

you can see the difference in the source code:
http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/browse/webapp2.py#574
while self.error() sets the status code but clears the response, self.abort() executes the function that takes care of the error handling.

Comment: The same results.  The error is displayed as indicated on the terminal but not in the browser.

Comment: found the issue. you should use self.abort() instead of self.error()

Comment: and for the records. it works also if you declare the app like in your original question.

Comment: You were almost there with your answer.  All that was needed to get this to work was to pull app.run() out of def main():  I am going to post the revised code up so others can find it.  Although I was using --debug on dev_appserver and noticed that this is still using CGI instead of WSGI.  Not certain on that.  I will add a new question on it though.

Comment: then you have something different in your code. removing the main() function does not write out the error message in the error_handler. you need to use self.abort() as you see from webapp2 source code. self.error does not execute anything else then setting a header and clearing the response.

Comment: You are right.  I was getting some response code from the development server popping into the browser, but it wasn't the message just the response code like:  

`Status: 401 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Length: 0`

Using self.abort(xxx) is the functionality I was looking for.